# Analytics - Intent Path graph export

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is there a way to export the Dialogflow-ES Analytics - Intent Path graph in a high resolution?

Please see screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for an API function or just copy-past?

Comment: Just copy-paste

Comment: Are you try to scroll a graph?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - due to the small frame the graph is presented in, I can't screenshot the entire graph without zooming out and losing clarity.

Comment: @Nick Is there any API to get data from the analytics tab - in dialogflow CX?

Comment: @parthkapadia https://github.com/joshbenner851/Flowlytics